# How do you edit a text outcome in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Im new to learning to code batch files.

Basically I have this script

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Current Serials-
echo.
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
wmic baseboard get serialnumber
pause
```

Which has this output

```
Current Serials-

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here
Insert Serial Number Here

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here
```

But I want the output to look like this

```
Current Serials-

Bios SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here
Diskdrive SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here, Insert Serial Number Here
BaseBoard SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here
```

So how do I do that?

Comment: Note: Every correct answer is going to involve a FOR loop. If you want easier output editing options than FOR loops, you could try PowerShell (or VBScript if you're legacy-limited) instead.

Comment: @TristanK not quite, it is possible without a loop, but it becomes complicated to the OPs. Hence why we simplify it with a loop. Have a look at Squashman's answer, for instance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is using a `for /F` loop to catch and split the output of wmic

```bat
@Echo off
 Echo(Current Serial numbers:
 For %%A in (Bios Diskdrive Baseboard) Do (
  For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%G in ('WMIC %%A get serialnumber') Do (
   For %%O in (%%G)Do Echo(%%A Serial Number: %%O
 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

To process files, strings or command outputs, use a `for` loop. See `for /?` (then read it again - it's one of the mightiest commands in `cmd`. Any time you invest into understanding it is a good investment.)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "drives=Diskdrive "
for /f %%a in ('wmic diskdrive get serialnumber^|findstr .') do set "drives=!drives!%%a, "
echo %drives:~0,-2%
```

As you are new to `cmd`, let me suggest [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/). Save it as favorite and visit it often.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it in a single line from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), with the help of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```sh
@PowerShell -NoP "Write-Host Current Serials-`r`n`r`nBIOS - $(GCim CIM_BIOSElement).SerialNumber`r`nPrimary Disk - $(GCim CIM_DiskDrive -F \"DeviceID Like '%%PHYSICALDRIVE0'\").SerialNumber.Trim()`r`nMotherboard - $(Get-CimInstance -Query \"Select * From CIM_Card Where Name='Base Board'\").SerialNumber"
```

Comment: Good one, but... What results in multiple serials (multiple disks) on the same line? The current results in a single serial when there are multiple disks.

Comment: See *Diskdrive SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here(disk #1), Insert Serial Number Here (disk#2)*, ....

Comment: I deliberately removed that possibility @ItWasn'tMe, by specifically requesting just the primary disk. _In my opinion it is not a usual requirement_. I deliberately used three different methods, a direct method, one with a filter, and one with a query, so that the most suitable method can be adapted for each as needed. My best guess is that the script is not going to be used only for these serial numbers, so my answer was designed such that it is simpler to extend for other computer information too.

Answer (score 0):

Because serialnumbers contains numeric, but the empty lines and the word `Serianumber` does not, I use `findstr` to determine which lines are serials and only `echo` them.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (Bios Diskdrive Baseboard) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic %%~i get serialnumber ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do echo %%~i Serialnumber- %%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option if you just want to use the standard output from the WMIC commands.

```
set /p ".=BIOS "<nul&wmic bios get serialnumber /value|more|findstr /I "serial"
set /p ".=DISKDRIVE "<nul&wmic diskdrive get serialnumber /value|more|findstr /I "serial"
set /p ".=BASEBOARD "<nul&wmic baseboard get serialnumber /value|more|findstr /I "serial"
```

Which would give you output like this.

```
BIOS SerialNumber=3ZB80R2
DISKDRIVE SerialNumber=0100_0000_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0016_7812.
BASEBOARD SerialNumber=/3ZB80R2/TW320709A3011C/
```

Or you could simplify it with a FOR command.

```
FOR %%G IN (BIOS DISKDRIVE BASEBOARD) DO set /p ".=%%G "<nul&wmic %%G get serialnumber /value|more|findstr /I "serial"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all disk serial numbers on the same line also delimited by a comma...

```bat
@echo off


set "_str=SerialNumber"
echo\ & echo\Current Serials-
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_gets=Bios,DiskDrive,BaseBoard"
set "_wmic=%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe"

echo\ & for %%i in (!_gets!)do for /f usebackq %%I in (`
     !_wmic! %%i get %_str%^|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe/v %_str%^|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe .
       `)do echo\%%i;|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /bl Bios; >nul && (echo\%%i !_str!- %%I
           )|| if /i "%%~i" == "BaseBoard" (echo=!_sn!&& echo\%%~i !_str!- %%~I
                   )else if "!_sn!" == "" (set "_sn=%%~i !_str!- %%~I"
                       )else set "_sn=!_sn!, %%~I"

>con:  %__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe -1|echo\Press any key to continue... & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

- Results

```bat
Current Serials-

Bios SerialNumber- XTE03A187
DiskDrive SerialNumber- 50026B776605D1D3, ZDZ0QKMT
BaseBoard SerialNumber- S0AFF01XDTS
Press any key to continue...
```

---

- In conventional layout:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo\
echo\Current Serials-
echo\ 

for %%i in (Bios,DiskDrive,BaseBoard)do ( 
     for /f usebackq %%I in (`%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe %%i get SerialNumber^|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe/v SerialNumber^|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe .`)do (
         echo\%%i;|%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /bl Bios; >nul && (
         echo\%%i SerialNumber- %%I ) || ( 
             if /i "%%~i" == "BaseBoard" (
              echo=!_sn!&& echo\%%~i SerialNumber- %%~I
            ) else if "!_sn!" == "" (
                  set "_sn=%%~i SerialNumber- %%~I"
                ) else (
                  set "_sn=!_sn!, %%~I"
                )
            )
        )

%__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe -1
endlocal
```